# Rails database setup on Travis-CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

I'm trying to use Travis Continuous Integration on a Rails project. The documentation says that the test db must be configured as following for SQLite3:

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: ":memory:"
  timeout: 500
```

But I'd like to keep my default configuration for local tests. Is it possible to keep both my local settings and the Travis requirements?

Comment: I don't get your question. Your local tests will not use .travis.yml anyways, will they?

Comment: Markus, according to Travis doc, I must edit my config/database.yml and replace my local test db for a in memory database: [SQLite Setup](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/database-setup/#sqlite3).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

My solution for this problem is fully based on [a blog post](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-test-your-rails-application-with-travis-ci-on-different-database-engines-1220.html) with a few differences:

1. Travis CI specific settings in `config/database.travis.yml`;
2. `cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml` in before script section of `.travis.yml`;
3. I don't have `config/database.yml` in source tree.

Here is full listing for both files:

```
# .travis.yml
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 1.9.3
env:
  - DB=sqlite
  - DB=mysql
  - DB=postgresql
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rake
before_script:
  - cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml
  - mysql -e 'create database strano_test'
  - psql -c 'create database strano_test' -U postgres


# config/database.travis.yml
sqlite: &sqlite
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%= Rails.env %>.sqlite3

mysql: &mysql
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password:
  database: strano_<%= Rails.env %>

postgresql: &postgresql
  adapter: postgresql
  username: postgres
  password:
  database: strano_<%= Rails.env %>
  min_messages: ERROR

defaults: &defaults
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  <<: *<%= ENV['DB'] || "postgresql" %>

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

Comment: There's no need to copy the database.yml in a before script. Your production credentials shouldn't be in a public github in any event, but using something like production: password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %> will work (it'll just be ignored by travis)

Comment: Yep and having production credentials though environment variables isn't always good idea as well. Therefore it is a common practice to leave config/database.yml file out of your repository.

Comment: @wik Why not? This is the first time I hear this.

Answer (score 6):

@mrm's blog post doesn't say anything about answering your question.
I faced the same problem where my postgreql credentials are different on my local machine than travis default. This is the simplest solution I came up with:

```
# config/database.yml
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: medscraper_test
  username: <%= ENV['TRAVIS'] ? 'postgres' : 'MY_TEST_USERNAME' %>
  password: <%= ENV['TRAVIS'] ? '' : 'MY_TEST_PASSWORD' %>
```

Note that Travis CI automatically sets TRAVIS environment variable.
Your solution would be:

```
# config/database.yml
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: <%= ENV['TRAVIS'] ? '":memory:"' : 'db/test.sqlite3' %>
  timeout: 500
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote [a blog post](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-test-your-rails-application-with-travis-ci-on-different-database-engines-1220.html) describing how to do this.

Comment: yours does allow to test against several databases, but it uses the same database.yml file everywhere, i.e. in local and production, which is an issue unless you deploy to heroku ;)

Comment: If you're worried about credentials, realize that `database.yml` goes through ERB—so you can reference a secure credentials hash to keep your passwords out of git. (We do this @twitter).

Comment: I thought we already discussed this in the above answer, doesn't it? ;)

Comment: Link now unreachable.

Comment: Here you go: https://web.archive.org/web/20120924203633/http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-test-your-rails-application-with-travis-ci-on-different-database-engines-1220.html