# ruby - script/server Errno::ENOENT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

When I try to run script/server I get this,
I am using rvm with rails, and also my project is using database.travis.yml


`/home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in '<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.18 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
/home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:926:in 'read': No such file or directory - /home/abcsoeasy/epz_lts-master/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:926:in 'database_configuration'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:437:in 'initialize_database'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:141:in 'process'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:113:in 'run'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/epz_lts-master/config/environment.rb:7:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in 'require'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in 'block in require'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in 'new_constants_in'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in 'require'
    from /home/abcsoeasy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in '<top (required)>'
    from script/server:3:in 'require'
    from script/server:3:in '<main>'`


Please guide me

Comment: You're using old rails with new rake or other gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see you error carefully it is stated

```
No such file or directory - /home/abcsoeasy/epz_lts-master/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
```

It means you have missed your `database.yml` file please add a `database.yml` Please look the example of it from [this](https://gist.github.com/erichurst/961978) link

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

Your app is missing database.yml file just create it.

May be this could also help.
[Rails database setup on Travis-CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321153/rails-database-setup-on-travis-ci)

Comment: Worked like anything!